Destroying scales
Suppose $\lambda$ is a cardinal with uncountable cofinality and $C\subseteq\lambda$ is a club of ordertype cf$(\lambda)$. Let $f=\langle f_\xi\mid\xi<\lambda^+\rangle$ be a scale consisting of functions in $\prod C^{(+)}/J^{bd}$, where $C^{(+)}:=\{\alpha^+\mid\alpha\in C\}$ and $J^{bd}$ is the ideal of bounded subsets of $\lambda$. Namely, $f$ has the following three properties:

For all $\xi<\lambda^+$, $f_\xi\in\prod C^{(+)}/J^{bd}$, i.e. $f_{\xi}:C^{(+)}\rightarrow\lambda$ and $f_{\xi}(a)<a$ for all $a$ above some $\mu<\lambda$;
$f$ is $<_{J^{bd}}$-increasing, i.e. if $\xi_1<\xi_2$ then $f_{\xi_1}<_{J^{bd}}f_{\xi_2}$;
If $g\in\prod C^{(+)}/J^{bd}$ then $g<_{J^{bd}}f_{\xi}$ for some $\xi<\lambda^+$.

For $h,g\in\prod C^{(+)}/J^{bd}$, $h<_{J^{bd}}$g means that $\{a\in C^{(+)}\mid h(a)\geq g(a)\}\in J^{bd}$.
I wonder whether one can destroy the third property with a proper forcing. More specifically, can we find a proper forcing $\mathbb{P}$ and a function $g\in\prod C^{(+)}/J^{bd}$ in the generic extension $V[\mathbb{P}]$ such that $$V[\mathbb{P}]\vDash “\ \forall\xi<\lambda^+\neg(g<_{J^{bd}}f_{\xi})"?$$
In other words, can $\mathbb{P}$ add a function $g\in\prod C^{(+)}/J^{bd}$ such that $f_\xi$ doesn't dominate $g$, for all $\xi<\lambda^+$?

Do you require that $\mathbb P$ preserves $\lambda$ as a cardinal or even that $\alpha^+$ is preserved for all $\alpha\in C$?

Hi @AndreasLietz! No I do not.

The canonical way to do that would be to force with "Hechler forcing relative to $\prod C^{(+)}/J^{\mathrm{bd}}$". That is the forcing $\mathbb P$ consisting of conditions $(s, f)$ so that $s$ is a proper initial segment of a function in $\prod C^{(+)}/J^{\mathrm{bd}}$ and $f\in\prod C^{(+)}/J^{\mathrm{bd}}$ ordered by
$$(t, g)\leq (s, f)\Leftrightarrow s\subseteq t\wedge \forall \alpha\in C\ f(\alpha)\leq g(\alpha)\wedge \forall\alpha\in \mathrm{dom}(t)\setminus\mathrm{dom}(s)\ t(\alpha)\geq f(\alpha).$$
As $\lambda$ and all elements of $C^{(+)}$ have uncountable cofinality, $\mathbb P$ is $\sigma$-closed, so proper. If $H$ is generic for $\mathbb P$ and $h$ is the union over the first coordinates appearing in $H$ then $h$ dominates any function in $\left(\prod C^{(+)}/J^{\mathrm{bd}}\right)^V$ on an unbounded set, in particular every member of the scale.
If $\lambda$ is singular then this forcing collapses $\lambda^{<\lambda}$ to $\mathrm{cof}(\lambda)$, in fact it adds a generic for $\mathrm{Col}(\mathrm{cof}(\lambda), \lambda^{<\lambda})$. (If $\lambda$ is regular, $\mathbb P$ preserves all cardinals $\leq\lambda$.)

What if one requires in addition that $V[\mathbb{P}]\vDash$ cof$(\lambda)<|\lambda|$?
